# Downloading a file in Windows store app

Tags: c#, download, windows-store-apps

I am having trouble downloading files through my windows store app. Here is my method for downloading:

```
private static async void DownloadImage()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("http://coolvibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/scifiwallpaper1.jpg");

        StorageFolder myfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = myfolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).GetResults();// this line throws an exception
        byte[] file = await message.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, file);
        var files = await myfolder.GetFilesAsync();

    }
```

On the marked line i get this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ListStalkerWin8.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: A method was called at an unexpected time.

Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time.
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling GetResults on an IAsyncOperation that has not yet completed, and so is not in a state where you can access the results (because they do not exist yet).

In fact, you don't need the call to GetResults at all, you just need:

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await myfolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: thnku very much Mario Stoilov and Chris W. i was sinking with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
StorageFile sampleFile = myfolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).GetResults();//
```

to

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await myfolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

seems to fix the problem, though i don't know why

Comment: It fixes the problem because the CreateFileAsync() function is asynchronous. In the Windows Store C# API (I dunno about WinJS) any asynchronous function will have the "Async" postfix. This means you have the ability to 'kick off' the file creation, do other stuff, then retrieve the StorageFile later when it's created. By adding the "await" keyword, you make the function synchronous; it's like saying "kick off file creation and don't come back till it's done". I know it's long but checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1